# SQL Azure and JAVA do not want to run query

Tags: java, azure, azure-sql-database

I have the following statement in JAVA:

```
String query = "SELECT H.Name as Name, R.RacesWon as Race FROM Horses AS H, Conditions AS C, Races AS R"+ "WHERE H.ID = R.HorseID AND C.ID = R.ConditionID";
```

I have connection to a SQL Azure database with 3 tables `Horses`, `Conditions` and `Races`.

I just made this join and I've got this exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'H'.

I do not know why and I have tried every possibility with `Horses`, `Races` and `Conditions` instead of H,C,R with AS , without AS without success.

Furthermore I have run :

```
String query = "SELECT Name  FROM Horses WHERE ID = 1";
```

and was OK.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't --> R"+ "WHERE <-- a run-on? =RWHERE

Comment: Thanks for this , I am very tired and I should not post such things here. Sorry guys and thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some concatenation issues.  As @lrb notes in the comments:

```
R"+ "WHERE
```

Would equal `RWHERE` which would cause an error.

Also use [SQL92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) syntax instead of SQL89 with `inner join`

Instead try:

```
String query = "SELECT 
                   H.Name as Name,
                   R.RacesWon as Race 
                 FROM Conditions as C
                 inner join Races AS R on C.ID = R.ConditionID
                 inner join Horses AS H on R.HorseID = H.ID";
```

Comment: Thanks for this , I am very tired and I should not post such things here. Sorry guys and thanks a lot

Comment: @Marian-EmanuelIonascu no worries.  Everyone needs another set of eyes.  Glad we got it working.